# Difference between "jdm. gehören" and "zu jdm. gehören"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I thought that the only way of expressing possession using the verb *gehören* is *jdm gehören*, but in a movie I heard:

> "Ich gehöre zu der Gemeinsamkeit."

Are the two forms interchangeable?

Comment: There is a simple answer: NO.

Answer (score 7):

The key difference is

- being property of someone: jdm. gehören

  > Das Buch gehört mir.
- being part of something: zu jdm/etw. gehören

  > Ich gehöre zu der Gruppe.

For example, there's a song by "Die Ärzte" with the following text:

> Ich bin dein Diener, du der Herr
> ab heut' gehör' ich dir allein.
> Bitte laß mich dein Sklave sein!

It's about "possession", here namely about being a slave.

In contrast, there's a song by "Marianne Rosenberg" with the following text:

> Er gehört zu mir, wie mein Name an der Tür.

It's not about possession, but about complementing each other and each one being a part of the whole.

"Ich gehöre dir" and "Ich gehöre zu dir" are two differing things. And they are not interchangeably.
In your sentences, it's about being a part of something, so you go with *zu jdm./etw. gehören*.

---

*Gehören* has a few more meanings but I think they're unrelated to this question. You can look them up in any dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I have found an example for gehören zu. "Arbeit gehört zum Leben"